# Proof of the theorem about Frobenius canonical form of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I can not find the proof of the following theorem:

If $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, $e_1(x),e_2(x),...e_n(x)$ its invariant factors and $F_1, F_2,...,F_k$ their companion matrices then $A$ is similar to $diag(F_1,F_2,...,F_k)$.

So far I know that two matrices are similar if their eigenmatrices have the same Smith normal forms. I also know that the Smith normal form of a companion matrix of a polynomial $p(x)$ is $diag(1,1,...,1,p(x))$, but I can not seem to deduce anything from that.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of an invariant factor?

Comment: The elememts on the diagonal of a Smith normal form.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am aware that the statement might be false because the script I readit from is poorly written at times and might be missinterpreted.

Comment: I think that's a correct definition at least; the invariant factors are the diagonal elements of the Smith normal form of (I guess the "eigenmatrix" in your terminology) $xI - A$.

Comment: This is very quick with an application of the [structure theorem over PIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain), but perhaps this is overkill

Comment: Thank you, but this is definitely too much for me since I, as a 2nd year undergraduate student, have not yet learned anything about modules. I can somewhat see how to apply this, but I guess I'm looking for a more elementary solution.

Comment: If we are given that two matrices whose eigenmatrix has the same smith normal form are necessarily similar, then we can also get proof immediately

Comment: We can prove that two matrices whose eigenmatrix has the same smith normal form are necessarily similar using Jordan form, but using Jordan form to prove Frobenius canonical form seems like a strange way to go

Comment: I have proven that two matrices whose eigenmatrices have the same Smith normal forms are similar using the polynomial division with a remainder.

Comment: But I can not see why A and diag(F1,...,Fk) have the same Smith normal forms even though I can see why they do share the same invariant factors.

Comment: Then my job is easy

Comment: How does that proof using polynomial division with remainder work?  Why are two matrices with the same associate Smith form similar?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/hmfkqptcnnyt

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that with overleaf!  Thanks for that, and thanks for writing that out

Comment: Any time, thank You for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the comments in the discussion, it suffices to find the smith normal form of $\operatorname{diag}(F_1,\dots,F_k)$. From your question, we know that there exist invertible matrix polynomials $U_j(x),V_j(x)$ such that
$$
U_j(x)(xI - F_j)V_j(x) = S_j(x) = \operatorname{diag}(1,\dots,1,e_j(x)).
$$
Now, define $U(x) = \operatorname{diag}(U_1(x),\dots,U_k(x))$ and $V(x) = \operatorname{diag}(V_1(x),\dots,V_k(x))$.  We have
$$
U(x) (xI - \operatorname{diag}(F_1,\dots,F_k))V(x) = \operatorname{diag}(S_1(x),\dots,S_k(x)),
$$
which is *almost* in Smith normal form. By selecting a suitable permutation matrix $P$, we can permute the diagonal elements to obtain
$$
P\operatorname{diag}(S_1(x),\dots,S_k(x))P^T = 
\operatorname{diag}(1,\dots,1,e_1(x),\dots,e_k(x)).
$$
So indeed, $\operatorname{diag}(F_1,\dots,F_k)$ has the same Smith normal form as $A$.

Comment: Alright, this is relatively simple, the mistake I made for some reason was thinking sizes of the blocks were determined by the number of of occurrences of each invariant factor. Instead we do it for all invariant factors that aren't equal to 1. And the size of the block is determined by the degree of the invariant factor. The size of the final matrix will be equal to the size of A since the product of all factors is equal to the characteristic polynomial which is of degree n.

Comment: Right.  Or if you want to keep the rule consistent, the block for the factor $1$ has size $0$ because $1$ is a polynomial with degree $0$.